# How can I place list icons in equal height?

Tags: html, css, list

I have a contact section for my info. My problem is that my info's section **icons are placed in wrong height**.

[image]

Im trying something like this:

```css
.contact-info ul{
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="col col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
 <div class="contact-info">
   <ul>
     <li>
       <i class="ti-mobile"></i><a href="tel:11111">111111</a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <i class="ti-mobile"></i><a href="tel:11111">11111</a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <i class="ti-email"></i><a href="mailto:info@info.gr">info@info.gr</a>
     </li>         
   </ul>
 </div>          
</div>
```

But i cant find it out. Any ideas?

Comment: its because of `justify-content: center;` which cenetrs everything and as such they are not aligned problery below each other anymore.

Comment: Can you share your entire CSS?

Comment: i dont have any css, this contact section i provided is given from my wordpress theme

Comment: @tacoshy can you provide the an example of how the css should be

Comment: @prvayah, what element is for the above css?

Comment: just updated my post

Answer (score 0):

1. remove: `.contact-info ul { justify-content:center; }`. This line will horizontally center within the box. As such they will not be prefectly aligned below eachother unless every line has the exact same width.
2. add: `.contact-info ul { flex-direction: column; }` to list the items below each other as in the picture.

On the other hand, you could also just simply delete the entire CSS as this behavior will be done this way then by default.

```css
.contact-info ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="col col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
  <div class="contact-info">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <i class="ti-mobile"></i><a href="tel:11111">111111</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="ti-mobile"></i><a href="tel:11111">11111</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="ti-email"></i><a href="mailto:info@info.gr">info@info.gr</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that was my second move. i tried your answer even with ```!important``` and it didnt worked. Weird...What might be wrong?

Comment: according to yur classnames, is it possible that you using bootrstrap?

Comment: my wordpress theme is using bootstrap. this is all i know:D

Comment: this problery the reason as it might overwrite everything. No way to tell without further and mroe specific information.